# Como puedo animar un listview completo

Tags: java, netbeans, listview, animación, scenebuilder

Como puedo animar con un lapso de tiempo de unos segundos todos lo elementos de un listview ya sean imágenes o texto con java NetBeans, que se muevan de izquierda a derecha.
Lo hago con un hilo pero no funciona del todo bien.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

**Animando Celdas de ListView**

[image: animación listcell]

sobrescribiendo el método `updateItem()` de `ListCell` se puede añadir una animación de la celda cuando hay un cambio . esto también se aplica cuando el item fue seleccionado o cuando se añade uno nuevo desde el evento de botón .

Esta es una app funcional de javafx en una sola clase que puede probar

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

        listView.getItems().setAll("gallo", "gato");
        listView.setMaxWidth(200);
        listView.setPrefWidth(200);
        listView.setCellFactory((p) -> {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String t, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(t, empty);
                    if (t != null && !empty && !this.isSelected()) {

                        TranslateTransition t1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), this);
                        t1.setFromX(-500);
                        t1.setToX(0);
                        t1.play();

                        setText(t);
                        setGraphic(new Circle(10, Color.YELLOWGREEN));
            
                    }

                }

            };
            return cell;
        });

        Button button = new Button("agregar");
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        button.setOnAction(e -> listView.getItems().add(textField.getText()));
        textField.setTranslateX(300);
        button.setTranslateX(300);
        button.setTranslateY(50);
        

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(listView, textField, button);
        var scene = new Scene(anchorPane, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo probare